# How do I get a parent vue component and child vue component to use the same data object?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a `Guestbook` component that I've divided into a `Sign` and `View` component.
I would like to pass or, even better, share entry data with my main guestbook component and my child View component, but I'm clueless how to achieve this.

I have the following code:

*/src/components/Guestbook.vue*

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Guestbook</h1>

    <SignGuestbook />
    <ViewGuestbook :entries="v_entries" />
    <ViewGuestbook :p_entries="v_entries" />
    <!-- Error: '[Vue warn]: Property or method "store" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.' -->
    <!-- <ViewGuestbook :entries="store" /> -->
    <!--   <ViewGuestbook :p_entries="store" /> -->
    <!-- Error: '[Vue warn]: Property or method "$store" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.' -->
    <!-- <ViewGuestbook :entries="$store" /> -->
    <!-- <ViewGuestbook :p_entries="$store" /> -->
</div>
</template>

<script>
import SignGuestbook from './SignGuestbook.vue'
import ViewGuestbook from './ViewGuestbook.vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import guestbook from './guestbook.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    entries: [
      { id: 1, name: 'stored 1', comment: 'comment' },
      { id: 2, name: 'stored 2', comment: 'comment' }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    entries: entries => {
      return entries
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    refreshList (state) {
      state.s_entries = guestbook.getItems()
    }
  }
})

export default {
  name: 'Guestbook',
  components: {
    SignGuestbook,
    ViewGuestbook
  },
  props: ['v_entries'],
  data () {
    return { comment: '', name: '', entries: ['test'] }
  },
  methods: {
    refreshList: async function () {
      this.entries = await guestbook.getItems()
      store.commit('refreshList')
      // this.$store = await guestbook.getItems()
      console.log('regular entries:', this.entries)
      console.log('stored entries:', this.store.getters.entries)
    }
  },
  async created () {
    await guestbook.authoriseAndConnect()
    await guestbook.createMutableData()
    await this.refreshList()
  }
}
</script>
```

*/src/components/ViewGuestbook.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>

    get entries attempt #1<br>
    <div v-for="entry in entries">
      an entry<br>
    </div>
    <br>
    get entries attempt #2<br>
    {{ entries }}
    <br>
    <!-- Error: '[Vue warn]: Property or method "$store" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.' -->
    <!-- stored entries<br>
    {{ this.$store }}
    <br>-->
    <br>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'ViewGuestbook',
  props: ['p_entries'],
  data () {
    return { entries: [
      { id: 1, name: 'child 1', comment: 'comment' },
      { id: 2, name: 'child 2', comment: 'comment' }
    ]}
  },
  async created () {
    this.entries = this.p_entries
  }
}

</script>
```

*/src/components/guestbook.js*

```
let app
let md

async function authoriseAndConnect () {
  const opts = {
    forceUseMock: true
  }
  let appInfo = {
    name: 'SAFE Guestbook Application',
    id: 'net.maidsafe.tutorials.web-app',
    version: '0.1.0',
    vendor: 'MaidSafe.net Ltd.'
  }
  app = await window.safe.initialiseApp(appInfo, null, opts)
  console.log('Authorising SAFE application...')
  try {
    const authReqUri = await app.auth.genAuthUri()
    console.log('Generated authentication URI...', authReqUri)
    const authUri = await window.safe.authorise(authReqUri)
    console.log('SAFE application authorised...')
    await app.auth.loginFromUri(authUri)
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn('Application authorisation was rejected', err)
  }
  console.log('Application connected to the network')
}

async function createMutableData () {
  console.log('Creating MutableData with initial dataset...')
  const typeTag = 15000
  md = await app.mutableData.newRandomPublic(typeTag)
  const initialData = {
    'random_key_1': JSON.stringify({
      name: 'parent 1',
      comment: 'comment'
    }),
    'random_key_2': JSON.stringify({
      name: 'parent 2',
      comment: 'comment'
    })
  }
  await md.quickSetup(initialData)
}

async function getItems () {
  const entries = await md.getEntries()
  let entriesList = await entries.listEntries()
  let items = []
  entriesList.forEach((entry) => {
    const value = entry.value
    if (value.buf.length === 0) return
    const parsedValue = JSON.parse(value.buf)
    items.push({ key: entry.key, value: parsedValue, version: value.version })
  })
  return items
}

module.exports = {
  authoriseAndConnect,
  createMutableData,
  getItems
}
```

*index.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

export default new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
})

// Error: unused variable
// let globalData = new Vue({
//   data: {
//     $store: {}
//   }
// })

// Error: '[Vue warn]: Property or method "$store" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.'
// Vue.mixin({
//   computed: {
//     $store: {
//       get: function () { return globalData.$data.$store },
//       set: function (newData) { globalData.$data.$store = newData }
//     }
//   }
// })
```

Expected (at least one of them):

```
get entries attempt #1
an entry
an entry
get entries attempt #2
[{ id: 1, name: 'stored 1', comment: 'comment' },{ id: 2, name: 'stored 2', comment: 'comment' }]
```

Result:

```
get entries attempt #1

get entries attempt #2


get entries attempt #1

get entries attempt #2
```

Comment: That sounds like a job for [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Parent to child properties are always shared objects. Changes in parent can be viewed by child. But, child is not supposed to modify it directly. Dispatch event for changes from child, and parent can save it to the original data.

Comment: Use global data conservatively... like for example for portal details/user details and roles. Other data can be managed by page itself. No need to over use a global store for everything

Comment: Well, it was the suggestion of @matthias-s, so I thought I'd show that as well. I don't want to use global stores though. This should ultimately be a module to be fitted into other projects.

Comment: @Teddy if parent to child properties are always shared objects and can be viewed by child, then I'd like to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share data, bind a data object from a parent component to a props object of a child component using v-bind.

Like so:

*/src/components/Guestbook.vue*

```
...
<ViewGuestbook v-bind:entries="d_entries" />
...

export default {
  name: 'Guestbook',
  components: {
    SignGuestbook,
    ViewGuestbook
  },
data () {
  return { d_entries: [] }
},
methods: {
  refreshList: async function () {
    this.d_entries = [
      { id: 1, name: 'placeholder 1', comment: 'comment' },
      { id: 2, name: 'placeholder 2', comment: 'comment' }
    ]
  },
},
async created () {
  this.refreshList()
}
...
```

*/src/components/ViewGuestbook.vue*

```
<template>
  <div>

    entries<br>
    <div v-for="entry in entries">
      {{ entry.name }}<br>
      {{ entry.comment }}<br>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'ViewGuestbook',
  props: {
    'entries': Array
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
https://codesandbox.io/s/62wvro7083

I solved this with my own little data store, its a very simple approach but works good enough for me without the necessity to dive into Vuex.

First, I create my data store somewhere before initializing anything else.

```
window.globalData = new Vue({
    data: {
        $store: {
            shared: {}
        }
    },
});
```

After that, I add a global Mixin that allows to get and set data to the global storage.

```
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        $store: {
            get: function () { return window.globalData.$data.$store },
            set: function (newData) { window.globalData.$data.$store = newData; }
        }
    }
});
```

Then, every component can access the data storage by `this.$store`. In an example codesandbox I have one `shared´ variable that holds the content, feel free to do it differently:

https://codesandbox.io/s/62wvro7083

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: It's a bit much that I see there, can't quite figure out where you put what, because I didn't say anything about Vuex. The solution above would be without Vuex. Try to do `window.globalData.....` instead

Comment: I edited my answer and provided a CodeSandbox example

Answer (score 0):

In ViewGuestbook.vue you have to copy the property into the main data.

In `created()` or `mounted()` hook do this:

```
this.entries = this.p_entries; //Just assign
this.entries = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.p_entries)); //Or clone it.
```